# Deserializing a collection that inherits list

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize an interface like this:

```
public interface MyCollection<T> extends List<T> {...}
```

And `MyCollection` has multiple implementations, say `public class MyBasicCollection<String>` and `public class MyOtherCollection<String>`.

I've added annotations on the interface, as in:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = MyBasicCollection.class, name = "basic"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = MyOtherCollection.class, name = "other")
})
public interface MyCollection<T> extends List<T> {...}
```

The detailed code to serialize and deserialize would be like:

```
MyCollection<String> testCollection = new MyBasicCollection<String>();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String serializedString = mapper.writeValueAsString(testCollection);
MyCollection<String> reconstructed = mapper.readValue(serializedString, new TypeReference<MyCollection<String>>(){});
```

And I would get a

> Can not find a deserializer for non-concrete Collection type

JsonMappingException.

However, if I change the last line to

```
MyCollection<String> reconstructed = mapper.readValue(serializedString, new TypeReference<MyBasicCollection<String>>(){});
```

It works perfectly.

Is there a way to make the deserialization work with the polymorphic type?

Comment: Why is it important to use your custom list types instead of letting Jackson pick an implementation of `List`?

Comment: @chrylis If I read to List<String> and then cast it to MyCollection<String>, it would cause a ClassCastException.

Comment: Yes, but why do you *need* a `MyCollection`? In nearly all cases, you should just be programming to `List`.

Comment: @chrylis I'm dealing with some codes other people wrote... so cannot avoid that lol